# django 2 fields form not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

2 of my fields from my `form` are not working when I try to search with them. I have about 10 fields total and they all work but those 2 don't.

this is part of my `forms.py` with the fields that are not working.

```
class AllTablesForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=250, required=False,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Title'}))


    .......

    redirectstatus = forms.IntegerField(label='', required=False,
                                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Redirect Status'}))
    created_at = forms.DateTimeField(label='', required=False, input_formats=["%Y-%m-%d"],
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Created At'}))
```

`redirectstatus` and `created_at` are not working. 
The format of my dates are like this.

In MySQL table:

```
2017-09-27 13:03:49
```

When i print out in django:

```
September 27, 2017 - 15:59:21
```

and the format for the redirect is simple.

```
200
300
...
```

I want to make the `created_at` something like the phpmyadmin date search.

This is my `views.py`

```
def search_form_table(request, pk):
    table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=pk)
    t = create_model(table_name.name)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AllTablesForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            title = cd['title']
            url = cd['url']
            description = cd['description']
            canonical = cd['canonical']
            robots = cd['robots']
            schematype = cd['schematype']
            redirectstatus = cd['redirectstatus']
            created_at = cd['created_at']
            query = t.objects.filter(title__icontains=title,
                                     url__icontains=url,
                                     description__icontains=description,
                                     canonical__icontains=canonical,
                                     robots__icontains=robots,
                                     schematype__icontains=schematype,
                                 redirectstatus__exact=redirectstatus,
                                     created_at__range=created_at)
            return render(request, 'search/search_table.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                                'form': form,
                                                                'details': query,
                                                                'detail': True})

        else:
            form = AllTablesForm()
    return render(request, 'search/search_table.html', {'form': form})
```

***ADDED***

if I don't put the `created_at` in the filter and leave only the `redirectstatus` and search 200 in the redirect search it doesn't give me anything and if put the `created_at` in the filter it gives me error:

```
ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Aren't they shown in templates ?

Comment: if i dont put the created_at in the filter...and leave only the redirectstatus...and search *200* in the redirect search anything...and if put the created_at in the filter it gives me error   **ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value**

Comment: Did you put any value in the `created_at` field when searching ?

Comment: yes..i ve changed created_at__range to created_at__gte and it doesn't give me any error but it doesnt give any results either

Comment: Try printing `created_at` in your views and check what value you are receiving.

Comment: i am receiving todays date in this format September 27, 2017 - 15:59:21

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155440/discussion-between-md-khairul-basar-and-omega).